# speed up sql INSERTs

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following method to insert millions of rows of data into a table (I use SQL 2008) and it seems slow, is there any way to speed up INSERTs?

Here is the code snippet - I use MS enterprise library

```
        public void InsertHistoricData(List<DataRow> dataRowList)
        {
            string sql = string.Format( @"INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Date],[Open],[High],[Low],[Close],[Volumn])
                VALUES( @DateVal, @OpenVal, @High, @Low, @CloseVal, @Volumn )");

            DbCommand dbCommand = VictoriaDB.GetSqlStringCommand( sql );
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "DateVal", DbType.Date);
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "OpenVal", DbType.Currency);
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "High", DbType.Currency );
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Low", DbType.Currency);
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CloseVal", DbType.Currency);
            DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Volumn", DbType.Int32);

            foreach (NasdaqHistoricDataRow dataRow in dataRowList)
            {
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "DateVal", dataRow.Date );
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "OpenVal", dataRow.Open );
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "High", dataRow.High );
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "Low", dataRow.Low );
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "CloseVal", dataRow.Close );
                DB.SetParameterValue( dbCommand, "Volumn", dataRow.Volumn );

                DB.ExecuteNonQuery( dbCommand );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this data inserted while SELECT activities might be concurrent?

Comment: Nope, I am the only user for that db.

Comment: In that case the advice on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751039/slow-bulk-insert-for-table-with-many-indexes about disabling indexes could be beneficial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using [bulk insert](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=323&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) instead.

> SqlBulkCopy lets you efficiently bulk
>   load a SQL Server table with data from
>   another source. The SqlBulkCopy class
>   can be used to write data only to SQL
>   Server tables. However, the data
>   source is not limited to SQL Server;
>   any data source can be used, as long
>   as the data can be loaded to a
>   DataTable instance or read with a 
>   IDataReader instance. For this example
>   the file will contain roughly 1000
>   records, but this code can handle
>   large amounts of data.

This example first creates a `DataTable` and fills it with the data. This is kept in memory.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string line = null;
bool firstRow = true;

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"c:\temp\table1.csv"))
{  
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                  if (firstRow)
                  {
                        foreach (var item in data)
                        {
                              dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                        }
                        firstRow = false;
                   }

                   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                   row.ItemArray = data;
                   dt.Rows.Add(row);
             }
      }
}
```

Then we push the `DataTable` to the server in one go.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConsoleApplication3.Properties.Settings.daasConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
      cn.Open();
      using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
      {
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 1);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 2);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 3);
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 4);
            copy.DestinationTableName = "Censis";
            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
      }
}
```

Comment: is definitely the best choice here since the question asker already has a sequence of data readers, these can be passed into a sql bulk copy...

Comment: +1 and wanted to say thank you, took me just a moment to adapt your sample code into my own solution, taking my similar CSV-to-SQL performance dilemma down from 30 seconds to under a second now. (Not a big deal, but I also wanted to note a mismatch curly brace in your sample above, where you are checking if `i == 0` for building the columns.)

Answer (score 1):

One general tip on any relational database when doing a large number of inserts, or indeed any data change, is to drop the all your secondary indexes first then recreate them afterwards.

Why does this work?  Well with secondary indexes the index data will be elsewhere on the disk than the data, so forcing at best an additional read/write update for each record written to the table per index.  In fact it may be much worse than this as from time to time the database will decide it needs to carry out a more serious reorganisation operation on the index.

When you recreate the index at the end of the insert run the database will perform just one full table scan to read and process the data. Not only do you end up with a better organised index on disk, but the total amount of work required will be less.

When is this worthwhile doing?  That depends upon your database, index structure and other factors (such as if you have your indexes on a separate disk to your data) but my rule of thumb is to consider it if I am processing more than 10% of the records in a table of a million records or more - and then check with test inserts to see if it is worthwhile.

Of course on any particular database there will be specialist bulk insert routines, and you should also look at those.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - looping through a record set and doing a million+ inserts on a relational DB, is the worst case scenario when loading a table. Some languages now offer record-set objects. For fastest performance SMINK is right, use BULK INSERT. Millions of rows loaded in minutes, rather than hours. Orders of magnitude faster than any other method.

As an example, I worked on a eCommerce project, that required a product list refresh each night. 100,000 rows inserted into a high-end Oracle DB, took 10 hours. If I remember correctly the top speed to when doing row-by-row inserts is aprox 10 recs/sec. Painful slow and completely unnecessary. With bulk insert - 100K rows should take less than a minute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Where the data come from? Could you run a bulk insert? If so, that is the best option you could take.