# BULK INSERT TMP TABLE sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert, bulkinsert, large-data-volumes

It is possible to use (BULK INSERT statement) to insert data from a temporary table to another table in the database ?

How can I use this operation since it has a temporary table more than 100,000 records?

Thanks

(sql server 2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temp table with only 100,000 records should be inserted into another table in very quickly certainly not long enough to timeout. If you are having timeouts, you have a different problem. First check to see if you have triggers that run a cursor or loop, check to see if your import statement has any correlated subqueries which would cause it to run slowly and check to see if the data is indexed (you can index temp tables but not table varaibles). Look at your execution plan to see where the bottelneck lies.

Another option is to run in batches of 1000 - 10,000 at a time (you may want to experiment to see how big a batch you can get away with.)

Answer (score 2):

No, BULK INSERT is only from a file.  You could dump the table out to a file and subsequently import it back in using bulk insert.

Is there a reason you can't just insert directly from the temp table into the target table? i.e. INSERT INTO targetTable SELECT * FROM #tempTable

Comment: When I run this command (INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM # targetTable tempTable) I get a timeout message.

There are several processes running on the database and if I run something that lets the database slowly, then i receive timeout.

Thanks

Comment: There are many options you could investigate for that problem, including tweaking the connection and command timeouts, explicitly specifying less restrictive locking hints in your query (only if appropriate), [temporarily disabling indexes on your destination table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751039/slow-bulk-insert-for-table-with-many-indexes/751062#751062) or trying SSIS.  Alternatively, is it feasible to schedule these inserts in a maintenance window when the database isn't under heavy load?