# Drop/Rebuild indexes during Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have got tables which has got more than 70 million records in it; what I just found that developers were dropping indexes before bulk insert and then creating again after the bulk insert is over. Execution time for the stored procedure is nearly 30 mins (do drop index, do bulk insert, then recreate index from scratch

Advice: Is this a good practice to drop INDEXs from table which has more than 70+ millions records and increasing by 3-4 million everyday.

Would it be help to improve performance by not dropping index before bulk insert ?

What is the best practice to be followed while doing BULK insert in BIG TABLE.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Have you tried it? Is the table in use during loading? Do you use a staging table?

Comment: I would worry about why you load 70 million existing rows each day when only 3-4 million are actually new.

Comment: @KM: I think 3-4 is the load into existing 70. Which also means it's perhaps 20 days of growth so far...

Comment: @gbn, after reading it again, that appears to be the case. Op really needs to give more info, there is no "one" way to do it, it depends on many factors.

Comment: 70 million records are till date; 1-2 million inserted everyday into that existing table. Execution is nearly taking 30 plus minutes... need to bring this down to meet SLA... i dont know whether disabling index and then reorganizing would help or not.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751039/slow-bulk-insert-for-table-with-many-indexes

Comment: As per the above link - its say disabled and then create indexes again. How it's different from dropping and then creating again.

Comment: The link says "disable" and "rebuild".  Show some effort.  Have you searched MSDN?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Like everything in SQL Server, "It Depends"

There is overhead in maintaining indexes during the insert and there is overhead in rebuilding the indexes after the insert. The only way to definitively determine which method incurs less overhead is to try them both and benchmark them.

If I were a betting man I would put my wager that leaving the indexes in place would edge out the full rebuild but I don't have the full picture to make an educated guess. Again, the only way to know for sure is to try both options.

One key optimization is to make sure your bulk insert is in clustered key order.

---

If I'm reading your question correctly, that table is pretty much off limits (locked) for the duration of the load and this is a problem.

If your primary goal is to increase availability/decrease blocking, try taking the A/B table approach.

The A/B approach breaks down as follows:

Given a table called "MyTable" you would actually have two physical tables (MyTable_A and MyTable_B) and one view (MyTable).

If MyTable_A contains the current "active" dataset, your view (MyTable) is selecting all columns from MyTable_A. Meanwhile you can have carte blanche on MyTable_B (which contains a copy of MyTable_A's data and the new data you're writing.) Once MyTable_B is loaded, indexed and ready to go, update your "MyTable" view to point to MyTable_B and truncate MyTable_A.

This approach assumes that you're willing to increase I/O and storage costs (dramatically, in your case) to maintain availability. It also assumes that your big table is also relatively static. If you do follow this approach, I would recommend a second view, something like MyTable_old which points to the non-live table (i.e. if MyTable_A is the current presentation table and is referenced by the MyTable view, MyTable_old will reference MyTable_B) You would update the MyTable_old view at the same time you update the MyTable view.

---

Depending on the nature of the data you're inserting (and your SQL Server version/edition), you may also be able to take advantage of partitioning ([MSDN blog on this topic.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/menzos/archive/2008/06/30/table-partitioning-sliding-window-case.aspx))