# Optimize oracle update query

Tags: oracle, optimization

How to optimize an update query:

```
UPDATE frst_usage vfm1 SET
  (vfm1.account_dn,
   vfm1.usage_date,
   vfm1.country,
   vfm1.feature_name,
   vfm1.hu_type,
   vfm1.make,
   vfm1.region,
   vfm1.service_hits,
   vfm1.maint_last_ts,
   vfm1.accountdn_hashcode) = (
    SELECT
      (SELECT vst.account_dn FROM services_track vst WHERE vst.accountdn_hashcode = vrd1.account_dn_hashcode AND rownum = 1),
      min(usage_date),
      country,
      feature_name,
      hu_type,
      make,
      region,
      service_hits,
      SYSDATE,
      account_dn_hashcode
    FROM raw_data vrd1
    WHERE vrd1.vin_hashcode = vfm1.vin_hashcode
          AND vrd1.usage_date IS NOT NULL AND rownum = 1
    GROUP BY account_dn, country, feature_name, hu_type, make, region, service_hits, vfm1.maint_last_ts, account_dn_hashcode
  );
```

the tables have indexes on all the columns available in the where conditions.

Still the execution is taking more than 4 hours. Below is the explain plan

[image: following is the execution plan of the query]

From the execution plan i could see that the select is good but the update is consuming more time resources, Is there a way i could optimize this.

Comment: The selects look ok but they're being executed 200k times, so that takes a while. The `where rownum = 1` things are suspicious - that's not deterministic. You might get better answers if you explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can index on `FRST_USAGE (VIN_HASHCODE)` help here? It is really hard to say not knowing your tables statistics. It looks like the problem is with TABLE ACCESS FULL on FIRST_USAGE.

Comment: @stee1rat, the indexes on columns in where clause exist alredy.

Comment: Do you really want to update every row in FRST_USAGE (200K rows)? If so there's no avoiding the FTS. (btw the question is incorrectly tagged "plsql". From the tag description: 'Questions with regular DML or DDL statements should be tagged with "sql" and "oracle", NOT with "plsql".')

Comment: I would try to insert the `services_track` table with the primary `FROM` of the main query, so as to not to do a index range scan for every row. That would improve execution time. But also, don't forget that if you have one or multiple indexes on `FRST_USAGE` and you update those columns, that will increase the execution time since the index also needs to be updated.

Comment: @Mat, The scenario we have is,
We need to update first usage of a feature called via mobile, which gets activated when used multiple applications like Pandora Radio, Iheart Radio, Slacker and many, So when any of these apps are used,A service call comes to the app and A row fills in the table service track,

Comment: Ponts to be noted, A Vin_hash can be associated to multiple account_dn_hash, And each account_dn_hash could be associated to different features that use viamobile feature, and we need to pick the min(usagedate) irrespective of feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think correlated subqueries may be an issue:

```
WHERE vrd1.vin_hashcode = vfm1.vin_hashcode
```

You should try merge clause, it could have dramatic impact on performance
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm

Below is example similar to yours. 10k sample rows, all columns indexed and statistics gathered:

Update (16s)

```
 SQL> update x1 set (v1, v2, v3, v4) =
  2  (
  3    select v1, v2, v3, min(v4)
  4    from x2
  5    where x1.nr = x2.nr
  6    group by v1,v2,v3
  7  );

9999 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:16.56

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3497322513

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT    |      |  9999 |   859K|  1679K  (5)| 05:35:59 |
|   1 |  UPDATE             | X1   |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | X1   |  9999 |   859K|    40   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   SORT GROUP BY     |      |     1 |    88 |    41   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| X2   |     1 |    88 |    40   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("X2"."NR"=:B1)
```

Merge(1,5s)

```
SQL> merge into x1 using (
  2    select nr, v1, v2, v3, min(v4) v4
  3    from x2
  4    group by nr, v1,v2,v3
  5  ) xx2
  6  on (x1.nr = xx2.nr)
  7  when matched then update set
  8  x1.v1 = xx2.v1, x1.v2 = xx2.v2, x1.v3 = xx2.v3, x1.v4 = xx2.v4;

9999 rows merged.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.25

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1113810112

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT        |      |  9999 |    58M|       |   285   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   1 |  MERGE                 | X1   |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                 |      |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN           |      |  9999 |    58M|       |   285   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL  | X1   |  9999 |   859K|       |    40   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     VIEW               |      |  9999 |    57M|       |   244   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   6 |      SORT GROUP BY     |      |  9999 |   859K|  1040K|   244   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| X2   |  9999 |   859K|       |    40   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("X1"."NR"="XX2"."NR")
```

Comment: The query is changed to pick appropriate records using  "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vin_hash ORDER BY usage_date) AS rn, and then merged
Thanks for the Merge query, it actually worked.
Both Cardinality reduced to 75.3K and cost reduced 19.1K to

Answer (score 0):

Indexes on the the target table reduce the performance.Disable the index before updating the table and rebuild the index once the update completed.

Comment: the query is a single query performing the select as well as update, How do i disable index in an update via select..??

Comment: first disable - "alter index .... unusable" , then query and finally "alter index .... rebuid" . But you must be careful about data integrity issues, indexes on primary key and unique columns

Comment: @napster pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751039/slow-bulk-insert-for-table-with-many-indexes

Comment: @Jaseer, If you would have looked at the query, the query is not an insert so that i could disable indexes, Its an update query and update of Table X happens based on a column C of table X  using the select conditioned on Column C of table X, SO if i disable index, then The select will perform badly.. And more over the select needs to execute for every record of update.. Thats how the data is available in the tabels.. If i have the chance to change the Table Design, I would have done it very easily, unfortunately I dont have the permissions to do so.. :) .

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve this using below query, and now the explain plan looks good.

```
    merge INTO FRST_USAGE vfu USING
    (SELECT tmp1.*
    FROM
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.vin_hash ORDER BY tmp.usage_date) AS rn,
        tmp.*
      FROM
        (SELECT vrd.VIN_HASHCODE  AS vin_hash,
          vrd.ACCOUNT_DN_HASHCODE AS actdn_hash,
          vst.ACCOUNT_DN          AS actdn,
          vrd.FEATURE_NAME        AS feature,
          vrd.MAKE                AS make,
          vrd.COUNTRY             AS country,
          vrd.HU_TYPE             AS hu,
          vrd.REGION              AS region,
          vrd.SERVICE_HITS        AS hits,
          MIN(vrd.USAGE_DATE)     AS usage_date,
          sysdate                 AS maintlastTs
        FROM RAW_DATA vrd,
          SERVICES_TRACK vst
        WHERE vrd.ACCOUNT_DN_HASHCODE=vst.ACCOUNTDN_HASHCODE
        GROUP BY vrd.VIN_HASHCODE,
          vrd.ACCOUNT_DN_HASHCODE,
          vst.ACCOUNT_DN,
          vrd.FEATURE_NAME,
          vrd.MAKE,
          vrd.COUNTRY,
          vrd.HU_TYPE,
          vrd.REGION,
          vrd.SERVICE_HITS,
          sysdate
        ORDER BY vrd.VIN_HASHCODE,
          MIN(vrd.USAGE_DATE)
        ) tmp
      )tmp1
    WHERE tmp1.rn              =1
    ) tmp2 ON (vfu.VIN_HASHCODE = tmp2.vin_hash)
    WHEN matched THEN
      UPDATE
      SET vfu.ACCOUNTDN_HASHCODE=tmp2.actdn_hash,
        vfu.account_dn          =tmp2.actdn,
        vfu.FEATURE_NAME        =tmp2.feature,
        vfu.MAKE                =tmp2.make,
        vfu.COUNTRY             =tmp2.country,
        vfu.HU_TYPE             =tmp2.hu,
        vfu.REGION              =tmp2.region,
        vfu.SERVICE_HITS        =tmp2.hits,
        vfu.usage_date          =tmp2.usage_date,
        vfu.MAINT_LAST_TS       =tmp2.maintlastTs;
```

below is the Explan plan:
[image]

Suggestions are allowed if there is any more optimizations i can do on this.